# Resolution Proofs

Tags: logic, proof-verification, algorithms

Im doing a past paper and this question came up, I've only seen Resolution proofs online and in the past with an OR symbol between two letters but this question is different. It asks me too pick the proofs that hold. Could someone offer some help and explanations, the answer is not needed as they are given.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)); the symbol :

> $\{ x,y \}$

stay for a (disjunctive) [clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)), that is a *disjunction* of literals :

$x \lor y$.

Thus, for example, the proof in i. amounts to :

1) $x \lor y$ --- premise

2) $x \lor \lnot y$ --- premise

3) $x$ --- from 1) and 2) by *resolution rule*

4) $\lnot x$ --- premise

> 5) $\square$ (the *empty clause*) --- from 3) and 4).